# Are there any tricks to integrate something like this?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How can we integrate?
Any tips would be helpful.
$$\int \frac{\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}\log(\sin(x)) \text dx$$

Comment: What did you try ?.

Comment: I looked at direct integration by parts, but couldn't see any obvious simplifications.

Comment: Make a Weierstrass substitution. The result requires the dilogarithm to express.